Except/before the IRGC vote/resolution, did the US Congress formally urge the EU to designate other organizations as terrorists?
H. Res. 288 passed by a large majority (411-14) on April 16 urges the EU to designate the IRGC as terrorists. Vote summary:

Urging the European Union to expeditiously designate the Islamic Revolutionary Guard Corps as a terrorist organization under Common Position 931, and for other purposes.

I'm curious: is this the first/only time that the US Congress is formally urging the EU to do something like that (i.e. designate a specific entity as terrorists) or has Congress done this before, and if so with respect to whom (else)?

At least one prior example is S. Res. 613, which was agreed on December 21, 2012:

A resolution urging the governments of Europe and the European Union to designate Hizballah as a terrorist organization and impose sanctions, and urging the President to provide information about Hizballah to the European allies of the United States and to support to the Government of Bulgaria in investigating the July 18, 2012, terrorist attack in Burgas.

Hizballah, or Hezbollah, is a political-military-terrorist organization (depending on who you talk to), based in Lebanon and closely linked to Iran and the IRGC.
The EU did in fact designate the military wing of Hezbollah for sanctions in a decision published on July 25, 2013. The military wing is characterized in the EU text as "the Jihad Council and all units reporting to it, including the External Security Organisation". That is the same wording used in UK sanctions from 2008. There was criticism of this action from some in the US, who wanted the entire group to be listed (as in the US, and as some European countries have subsequently done), partly because of doubts whether it was possible or reasonable to distinguish the military and political sides. Hezbollah itself responded to claim that their listing was "written with an American hand in Zionist ink".
